# Can anyone tell me how does conservative forces work? Confused

Tags: forces, potential-energy, conventions, vector-fields, conservative-field

From vector calculus, I'd learnt that a conservative vector field satisfies
$$
\textbf{F} = \boldsymbol{\nabla} g
$$
which $\textbf{F}$ is the gradient of some scalar-valued function, and $g$ is the function.

But in physics, I see someone saying
"definition of conservative forces is that is there exists a scalar function $V$ for a field $\textbf{F}$ which satisfies this condition"
$$ \textbf{F}=- \boldsymbol{\nabla} V$$

Why does a negative sign exist and why does $\textbf{F} = \boldsymbol{\nabla} g$ in the first place? I don't want to take it as it be.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: [Conservative vector field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field) - Wikipedia

Comment: The sign is purely conventional. In electrostatics you use it, in fluid dynamics when considering potential flow you don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is very simple: if $\vec{F}$ is a conservative vector field, then $\vec{G} = -\vec{F}$ is also a conservative vector field. So mathematically, the choice to include the minus sign or not doesn't change anything. But *physically*, the minus sign is important because it lets the physical quantities match our physical intuition. When we write $\vec{F} = -\nabla V$, we mean physically that the force $\vec{F}$ arises from a *potential energy* function $V$. Intuitively, we like to think that such a force pushes from high to low potential energy -- think about how gravity causes an object to fall from high to low gravitational potential energy, or a spring pushes a block from high to low elastic potential energy. Since $\nabla V$ is a vector that points in the direction of the sharpest *increase* in $V$, then $\vec{F} = -\nabla V$ pushes the object in the direction of the sharpest *decrease* in $V$.

Of course, this is all a convention -- if you'd like, you can define a "potential schmenergy" function $\tilde{V} = -V$, and then $\vec{F} = + \nabla \tilde{V}$. None of the physics would be changed, except that objects would fall from low to high potential schmenergy, which might go against the grain of your intuition.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 
However, I'm not so clear about why we take "the sharpest decrease" in this case if the signs doesn't matter.

Comment: Two reasons. First, because it's how we as humans psychologically like to think about it. When a ball rolls down a hill, we like to say that the potential energy decreases, not increases. Since the force from gravity is pushing in the direction of decreasing potential energy, we need the minus sign. Second, because when the minus sign is included that way, we find that the sum of kinetic and potential energy is conserved in some cases. If you wrote $F=\nabla V$, then $T-V$ would be your conserved energy ($T$ is kinetic energy).